# margin being included in link - need to exclude margin from linked area

Tags: css, html

I have this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96urhqcz/

There are 4 divs in a row - the HTML looks like this:

```
  <div class="g-1-4 app">
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://link1/">
    <div style="margin:10px; padding: 30px 0px; background:#E74C3C" class="app">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-comments-o" width="50%" style="display:block; margin:auto" src="/static/launcher/comments-o"></i> 
        Link Number 1
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="g-1-4 app">
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://link2/">
    <div style="margin:10px; padding: 30px 0px; background:#9D55B8" class="app">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-paper-plane" width="50%" style="display:block; margin:auto" src="/static/launcher/paper-plane"></i> 
        Link Number 2
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="g-1-4 app">
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://link3/">
    <div style="margin:10px; padding: 30px 0px; background:#3395DD" class="app">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-street-view" width="50%" style="display:block; margin:auto" src="/static/launcher/street-view"></i> 
        Link 3
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="g-1-4 app">
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://link4/">
    <div style="margin:10px; padding: 30px 0px; background:#00838F" class="app">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-line-chart" width="50%" style="display:block; margin:auto" src="/static/launcher/line-chart"></i> 
        Link 4
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The CSS for g-1-4 looks like this:

```
.g-1-4{
    width: 25%;
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle - the margins between the boxes are 'linked' to the appropriate box.

Ultimately I'm trying to have a 4-across layout, but have the margins *not* linked. When a user mouses between the boxes I want it to be a regular mouse with no clickability.

I'm sure it's something really simple I'm missing - but I can't seem to correct it.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Your problem is that you have padding on the left and right side, which is the reason why your links are expending around the "real" divs. Consider using margin instead of padding.

Comment: I do have 10px of margin around the edge, but that seems to make no difference (if you expand the margin and decrease the padding - the margin area is still linked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the margin off of the `<div>` and add it to the `<a>` that's wrapping the div. Also add `style="display:block:"` to the `<a>`.

[This CodePen has the updates.](https://codepen.io/beepye/pen/GvrVym)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a fixed width to your divs, and using *flexbox* they will be automaticaly displayed with space which is not *'linked'*.

Hope this little code will help you.

```css
.flex {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-around;
}

.div1, .div3 {
  width : 120px;
  height : 120px;
  background-color : red;
}

.div2, .div4 {
  width : 120px;
  height : 120px;
  background-color : blue;
}

p {
  margin : 0;
  color : white;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size : 12px;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <a href="#" class="div1">
    <p>LINK 1</p>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="div2">
    <p>LINK 2</p>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="div3">
    <p>LINK 3</p>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#" class="div4">
    <p>LINK 4</p>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I really like the flexbox idea - I'm not sure how it would impact other areas of the site however, so it would require more testing. I upvoted to reflect the appropriateness of the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Question - is there a way to do this with a % width? Or must you use fixed width with flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coming from your using the table cell display method.

```
.g > div,
.g-m > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

I also support the flex box usage as pointed out by Louis.

Answer (score -1):

What is happening is that the link element is expanding to the 100% of the container div to get some space you could set a specific width for the a tag or you could add some padding to the container element, you will have to play with padding and width to make it look good though.

https://jsfiddle.net/96urhqcz/1/

```
.g-1-4{
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```